# How to configure ports for hostname and localhost?

Tags: hadoop, port, firewall, ambari

I am running a browser on the single node Hortonworks Hadoop cluster(HDP 2.3.4) on Centos 6.7:

- With `localhost:8000` and `<hostname>:8000`, I can access Hue. Same works for Ambari at 8080
- However, several other ports, I only can access with the hostname. So with  e.g. `<hostname>:50070`, I can access the namenode service. If I use `localhost:50070`, I cannot setup a connection. So I assume localhost is blocked, the namenode not.

How can I set up that `localhost` and `<hostname>` have the same port configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This likely indicates that the NameNode HTTP server socket is bound to a single network interface, but not the loopback interface.  The NameNode HTTP server address is controlled by configuration property `dfs.namenode.http-address` in hdfs-site.xml.  Typically this specifies a host name or IP address, and this maps to a single network interface.  You can tell it to bind to all network interfaces by setting property `dfs.namenode.http-bind-host` to `0.0.0.0` (the wildcard address, matching all network interfaces).  The NameNode must be restarted for this change to take effect.

There are similar properties for other Hadoop daemons.  For example, YARN has a property named `yarn.resourcemanager.bind-host` for controlling how the ResourceManager binds to a network interface for its RPC server.

More details are in the Apache Hadoop documentation for [hdfs-default.xml](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml) and [yarn-default.xml](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml).  There is also full coverage of multi-homed deployments in [HDFS Support for Multihomed Networks](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsMultihoming.html).